# Need to reroute example/admin/abc/123 to example/User/xyz?i=123 without affecting the other urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

How can I rewrite the uri
https://www.example.com/user/qr-scan-result/6A210C91-C99D-46DC-8A17-7633CF73AA34
to
https://www.example.com/User/QR/qrScanResult.php?qr=6A210C91-C99D-46DC-8A17-7633CF73AA34
in php
I have many other urls in the project and I donot want to affect any of the other uri

I tried to follow this link https://github.com/phprouter/main but couldnt complete

Comment: This is pretty much identical to the linked duplicate. The principle is exactly the same. Just substitute `/server/<ServerName>` with `/user/qr-scan-result/<code>` and `/server/index.php?Server=<ServerName>` with `/User/QR/qrScanResult.php?qr=<code>` - you can make the regex more specific to match the format of your `<code>` (uppercase A-F, digits and hypen). Note that if you have many other similar rules then the order can be important. If you are still having problems then edit your question to include your complete `.htaccess` file with your attempted code in-place.